# Как создать проект для работы с win 32 api

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

Хочу отметить, что у меня Visual Studio 2019, пакет v142. Как мне создать проект для работы с win 32 api.  Нужно обязательно создать проект типа Win32 или CLR(хотя как я понял CLR это для Windows Forms, а оно имеет различие c win api). Если нужно создавать проект какого-то другого типа(win32 или CLR), то как его скачать в visual studio installer, потому что ничего похожего я там не вижу. Или достаточно создать пустой проект и подключить к нему библиотек ?

Comment: Ставите студию с оснасткой для десктопной разработки на C++ - соответствующий тип проектов будет доступен в студии.

Comment: А можно как-то проще, чтобы не удалять студию, и не ставить ее обратно. А к примеру докачать необходимы компоненты в инсталлере?

Comment: А я вроде нигде не упоминал, что ее надо удалять...

Answer (score 0):

Выбираете в меню file->new->project. Там выбираете: Select the new windows desktop wizard project. В Configuration: options:Select the application type (desktop application (.exe)). Все вроде.